# Calculating the point of intersection of two parabolas

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

I recently wrote a function to calculate the intersection point(s) of two parabolas.  Working it out on paper was a nightmare, but I eventually did it (I think it's correct), and ended up with:

\$ x = \frac{\sqrt{c_2 - c_1 + \frac{b_1^2}{4a_1} - \frac{b_2^2}{4a_2} + E}}{\sqrt{a_2 - a_1}} - \frac{b1 - b2}{2(a1 - a2)} \$

with

\$ E = \frac{b_1^2a_2^3(a_2 - 2a_1^2) - a_1^3b_2^2(a_1 - 2a_2^2) - 2a_1^2a_2^2b_2(b_2 - b_1)}{(4a_1^2a_2^2)(a_1 - a_2)^2} \$

For any two parabolas \$ a_1x^2 + b_1x + c_1 = 0\$ and \$a_2x^2 + b_2x + c_2 = 0\$.

That can't be the fastest way to do it, I must be missing something. Does anyone know of any better ways I could implement parabola to parabola intersection point calculations?

The function I wrote is below:

```
def parabola_to_parabola_poi(a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2):
    """
    Calculate the intersection point(s) of two parabolas.
    """
    a1_sqrd, a2_sqrd = a1*a1, a2*a2
    b1_sqrd, b2_sqrd = b1*b1, b2*b2
    c1_sqrd, c2_sqrd = c1*c1, c2*c2

    E1 = b1_sqrd*a2_sqrd*a2*(a2 - 2*a1_sqrd)
    E2 = a1_sqrd*a1*b2_sqrd*(a1 - 2*a2_sqrd)
    E3 = 2*a1_sqrd*a2_sqrd*b2*(b2 - b1)
    E4 = (4*a1_sqrd*a2_sqrd)*(a1 - a2)*(a1 - a2)

    E = (E1 - E2 - E3)/E4

    F = (c2 - c1 + b1_sqrd/(4*a1) - b2_sqrd/(4*a2) + E)/(a2 - a1)
    G = (b1 - b2)/(2*(a1 - a2))

    if not F:
        px = math.sqrt(F) - G
        py = a1*px*px + b1*px + c1
        return [
            (px, py)
            ]
    elif F < 0:
        return []
    sqrt_F = math.sqrt(F)

    px1 = sqrt_F - G
    px2 = -sqrt_F - G

    py1 = a1*px1*px1 + b1*px1 + c1
    py2 = a1*px2*px2 + b1*px2 + c1

    return [
        (px1, py1),
        (px2, py2)
        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems as though I SIGNIFICANTLY overcomplicated the equation for some reason. I just did the equation it a second time and I got something much nicer:

For any two parabolas \$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0\$ and \$dx^2 + ex + f = 0\$, we get:

\$
ax^2 - dx^2 + bx - ex + c - f = 0 \\
x^2(a - d) + x(b - e) = f - c
\$

Now it's just a matter of completing the square.

\$
x^2(a - d) + x(b - e) + \frac{(b - e)^2}{4(a - d)} = f - c + \frac{(b - e)^2}{4(a - d)} \\
(x\sqrt{a - d} + \frac{b - e}{2\sqrt{a - d}})^2 = f - c + \frac{(b - e)^2}{4(a - d)} \\
(a - d)(x + \frac{b - e}{2(a - d)})^2 = f - c + \frac{(b - e)^2}{4(a - d)} \\
x + \frac{b - e}{2(a - d)} = \sqrt{\frac{f - c + \frac{(b - e)^2}{a - d}}{a - d}} \\
x = \sqrt{\frac{f - c + \frac{(b - e)^2}{a - d}}{a - d}} - \frac{b - e}{2(a - d)} \\
\$

I don't know how I ended up with the monster I originally posted, but this seems much more reasonable.

Comment: Even simpler: apply the quadratic formula to \$(a-d)x^2 + (b-e)x + (c-f)\$.

Comment: You lost a factor of four in the denominator of \$(b-e)^2\$ between the third-to-last equation and the second-to-last equation.

Comment: Also missed a \$\pm\$ sign.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the other answers have pointed out that evaluation the Quadratic Forumula is a simpler way solve this equation.

Here is my solution:

```
import math

def find_intersect(a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2):
    a = a1-a2
    b = b1-b2
    c = c1-c2

    inner_calc = b**2 - 4*a*c

    # Check if `inner_cal` is negative. If so, there are no real solutions.
    # Thus, return the empty set.
    if inner_calc < 0:
        return set()

    square = math.sqrt(inner_calc)
    double_a = 2*a
    answers = [(-b + square)/double_a, (-b - square)/double_a]

    # Using `set()` removes any possible duplicates.
    return set(answers)
```

If you were interested in returning all possible answers (real and imaginary), you could use the [`cmath` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) which automatically handles negative numbers in its `sqrt()` function. All you need to change is remove the if-statement and import `cmath` instead of `math`:

```
import cmath

def find_intersect(a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2):
    a = a1-a2
    b = b1-b2
    c = c1-c2

    square = cmath.sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
    double_a = 2*a
    answers = [(-b + square)/double_a, (-b - square)/double_a]

    # Using `set()` removes any possible duplicates.
    return set(answers)
```

Comment: Yes, you have to test `b**2 - (4*a*c)` for a negative value before calling `math.sqrt`.  In the code above, you go ahead and take the square root (using `cmath.sqrt`), then do a bunch of other operations, and then in the end you _still_ need a conditional (`if result.imag == 0.0`) and if it's false, you throw away the results of all your previous calculations. It seems more efficient to me to just stop after computing `b**2 - (4*a*c)` when the result is negative.

Comment: Good catch. I have updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: I'd still prefer `d = b*b - 4*a*c` followed by `if d < 0:`, and in the case where d >= 0, _then_ compute the square root.

Comment: In most trivial cases, I would tend to disagree with you. I would rather do an extra trivial operation than store another local variable. However, in this case, `cmath.sqrt` is probably not a trivial operation. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: Yes, I suppose I tend to think of square root as a heavy-weight operation. If I really wanted to minimize operations (at the expense of extra variables) I could have stored the results of `b*b` and `4*a*c` in temporary variables and following this with something like `if temp1 < temp2` ... but that is so extreme that I didn't even think of it until you made the tradeoff clear.  I may also have been influenced by the fact that \$b^2 - 4ac\$ is such an important quantity in math that we have a name for it (discriminant), which makes it easier to think of naming it something in the code.

Comment: At this point, I think its just a matter of preference :D

Answer (score 3):

Given two parabolas \$ f_1(x) = a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1\$ 
and \$ f_2(x) = a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2\$,
you are asking to find \$x\$ such that \$f_1(x) = f_2(x)\$.

That is, you want \$f_1(x) - f_2(x) = 0\$.  But if you write this as a difference of two polynomials in the usual way, you are trying to solve

\[f_1(x) - f_2(x) =  (a_1 - a_2) x^2 + (b_1 - b_2) x + (c_1 - c_2) = 0.\]

Apply the usual quadratic formula with \$ a = a_1 - a_2\$, \$ b = b_1 - b_2\$, 
and \$ c = c_1 - c_2\$. The result is

\[ x = \frac{-(b_1 - b_2) \pm \sqrt{(b_1 - b_2)^2 - 4(a_1 - a_2)(c_1 - c_2)}}
{2(a_1 - a_2)}.\]

You could try to manipulate this further, but I don't think you'll get anything easier to compute. Note that there are either *two*, one, or no possible solutions for \$x\$, depending on the value of the expression under the square root.  Also note that we could write \$b_2 - b_1\$ instead of \$-(b_1 - b_2)\$, but I think writing it this way is easier to check against the standard formula and is also suggestive of the best code to compute the result.